# How does Sync work when working with Git in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

How does Git Sync button work in Visual Studio Team Explorer? What are the actual executed Git commands and their order?

Comment: Exact commands, no. Visual Studio calls into LibGitSharp which calls to LibGit2 which talks directly to the remote repo (with no command line underneath it). The end result is a Fetch & Push (if no merge conflicts occur).

Answer (score 5):

It does the equivalent of a `fetch` + `merge` + `push`, which is the same as `pull` + `push`